# Rails, validates_format_of - minimum 4 alphabetic characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I validate a field - so that it contains at least 3 alphabetic characters.

```
Valid:
Something, Foobar 111. 

Invalid:
.......
```

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More railsy way is to validate in the model automatically

```
validate :yourvalue_must_contain_at_least_3_alphabetic_characters

protected 

def yourvalue_must_contain_at_least_3_alphabetic_characters 
 errors.add(:yourvalue, 'should have at least 3 alphabetic characters') if yourvalue.gsub(/[^A-Z]/i,"").size > 2 
end
```

Answer (score 7):

While i prefer DanSingerman's solution, you can also go pure regex based:

```
   validates_format_of :password, :with => /([^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]*){3,}/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `validate` method for that.

e.g.

in your model

```
protected

def validate
  unless your_field.gsub(/[^A-Z]/i,"").size > 2
    errors.add("your_field", "Must contain at least 3 alphabetical characters")
  end
end
```

More on Rails validations here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html